How to write custom logs into LAW using Azure OpenTelemetry in databrick notebook
I have to maintain custom logs of azure ADB into Log Analytics Workspace.
Need to write custom logic using OpenTelemetry to store custom logs into LAW.

Do you want to Send Azure Databricks application logs to Azure Monitor? what type of logs do want to send? you  using OpenTelemetry with code ? please the details you tried/ code you tried ?

To integrate Azure OpenTelemetry for writing custom logs into Log Analytics Workspace from an Azure Databricks notebook, follow these steps:

Create an Azure Databricks Workspace and an Azure Log Analytics Workspace.
Go to Databricks Workspace > Clusters.
Create a new cluster with Databricks Runtime 7.5.
In the cluster's Advanced Options, add the initialization script path:

dbfs:/appinsights/appinsights_logging_init.sh





Run the following code to create the initialization script
%python  
dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/appinsights/appinsights_logging_init.sh","""  
#!/bin/bash  
  
STAGE_DIR="/dbfs/appinsights/"  
APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY="xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"  
LOG_ANALYTICS_WORKSPACE_ID="xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"  
LOG_ANALYTICS_PRIMARY_KEY="xxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"




For the full code of appinsights_logging_init.sh, refer to this link and to configure Azure Databricks to send events to Application Insights.


import org.apache.log4j.LogManager
val  log  =  LogManager.getRootLogger
log.warn("WARN: Custom Log from Databricks")
log.info("INFO: Custom Log from Databricks")



To log custom messages in Databricks, use the following Scala code:

You can find the logs in Compute.

To see logs in  Azure Application Insights, use the following KQL query:
traces 
| project 
  message,
  severityLevel



